# RijndaelManaged can not decrypt

Tags: c#, .net, security, encryption, rijndaelmanaged

The code can be found at: http://pastebin.com/3Yg5bHra

My problem is, that when I decrypt then nothing gets returned at all. Nothing gets decrypted.

It goes wrong somewhere around line 111-114. The cryptoStream (csDecrypt) is empty, eventhough I put data into the memorystream (msDecrypt)

**EDIT**
Nudier came up with a solution

Comment: Consider making your sample 4 times smaller - remove all string conversion code and just have byte arrays. Otherwise post to codereview site.

Comment: Where do you set your encryption key and the initialization vector?

Comment: I have uploaded some more code - thank you Alexei Levenkov, good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Function for encrypting propose
static string SymmetricEncryption(string str, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
{

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

try
{

//---creates a new instance of the RijndaelManaged class---
RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

//---creates a new instance of the CryptoStream class---
CryptoStream cryptStream =new CryptoStream(ms, RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, IV),

CryptoStreamMode.Write);

StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptStream);

//---encrypting the string---
sWriter.Write(str);

sWriter.Close();

cryptStream.Close();

//---return the encrypted data as a string---
return System.Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

}
catch (Exception ex)

{
Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

return (String.Empty);
}

}


//Function for Decrypting propose
static string SymmetricDecryption(string str, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
{

try

{

//---converts the encrypted string into a byte array---
byte[] b = System.Convert.FromBase64String(str);

//---converts the byte array into a memory stream for decryption---
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b);

//---creates a new instance of the RijndaelManaged class---
RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

//---creates a new instance of the CryptoStream class---
CryptoStream cryptStream = new CryptoStream(ms, RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, IV),

CryptoStreamMode.Read);

//---decrypting the stream---
StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(cryptStream);

//---converts the decrypted stream into a string---
String s = sReader.ReadToEnd();

sReader.Close();

return s;

}
catch (Exception ex)
{

Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

return String.Empty;

}

}



//Main function execute the functions
RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

//---generate key---
RMCrypto.GenerateKey();

byte[] key = RMCrypto.Key;

Console.WriteLine(“Key : “ + System.Convert.ToBase64String(key));

//---generate IV---
RMCrypto.GenerateIV();

byte[] IV = RMCrypto.IV;
Console.WriteLine(“IV : “ + System.Convert.ToBase64String(IV));

//---encrypt the string---
string cipherText = SymmetricEncryption(“This is a test string.”, key, IV);

Console.WriteLine(“Ciphertext: “ + cipherText);

//---decrypt the string---
Console.WriteLine(“Original string: “ + SymmetricDecryption(cipherText, key, IV));
```

Comment: Thank you nudier, it is working.
I have refactored the code to fit my class: [link](http://pastebin.com/gugiNNTn). RMCrypto.GenerateKey(); and  RMCrypto.GenerateIV(); are not necessary.
I don't really know where the difference is in my code before and code now, but it works.

Thank you

Comment: @CasperThuleHansen Your variant save me with urlSaveEncode ))

Comment: @DmitrijPolyanin awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Remember to set the key for Encryption and Decryption and also de IV(Initialization Vector)

Answer (score 0):

```
     public AesData GetAesData()
    {

        //Before assigned the key and IV you have to generate it first this way.

        _rijndaelObj.GenerateKey();

        _rijndaelObj.GenerateIV();


        string key = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_rijndaelObj.Key);
        string iv = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_rijndaelObj.IV);
        return new AesData(key, iv);
    }
```

Comment: The keys are generated by default when creating a new rijndaelmanaged object