# MediCare Card Encryption with ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, encryption

I am giving free consultation for a non profit organisation who want a simple system to manage   multiple groups with a schedule component etc and also manage the medical informations of the kids. Its all on a excel file but the problem is not very convenient for the nurse. So I am building this asp.net application and I hit a wall when it concerns encryption of sensitive data. I have writen this c# code following books and recomandations of this website. I am doing it right ?

```
 using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class SymmetricEncryptionWithPassword : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Encrypt_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the algorithm from the values on the page.
        SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm = new AesManaged();

        byte[] generatedKey = null;
        byte[] generatedIV = null;

        TextBox salt = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox2");
        TextBox ssn = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1");

        salt.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(GenerateSalt());

        GetKeyAndIVFromPasswordAndSalt(this.password.Text, Convert.FromBase64String(salt.Text), symmetricAlgorithm, ref generatedKey, ref generatedIV);

        symmetricAlgorithm.Key = generatedKey;
        symmetricAlgorithm.IV = generatedIV;

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor(symmetricAlgorithm.Key, symmetricAlgorithm.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] plainTextAsBytes = new UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(ssn.Text);
            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextAsBytes, 0, plainTextAsBytes.Length);
        }

        symmetricAlgorithm.Clear();

        byte[] encryptedData = memoryStream.ToArray();
        ssn.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);


    }


    protected void Decrypt_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the algorithm from the values on the page.
        SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm = new AesManaged();

        byte[] generatedKey = null;
        byte[] generatedIV = null;

        TextBox txt = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox2");
        TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1");
        GetKeyAndIVFromPasswordAndSalt(this.password.Text, Convert.FromBase64String(txt.Text), symmetricAlgorithm, ref generatedKey, ref generatedIV);

        symmetricAlgorithm.Key = generatedKey;
        symmetricAlgorithm.IV = generatedIV;

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor(symmetricAlgorithm.Key, symmetricAlgorithm.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] encryptedDataAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(txt1.Text);
            cryptoStream.Write(encryptedDataAsBytes, 0, encryptedDataAsBytes.Length);
        }

        symmetricAlgorithm.Clear();

        byte[] decryptedData = memoryStream.ToArray();

        txt1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);

               }


    private static byte[] GenerateSalt()
    {
        const int MinSaltSize = 8;
        const int MaxSaltSize = 16;

        // Generate a random number to determine the salt size.
        Random random = new Random();
        int saltSize = random.Next(MinSaltSize, MaxSaltSize);

        // Allocate a byte array, to hold the salt.
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[saltSize];

        // Initialize the cryptographically secure random number generator.
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

        // Fill the salt with cryptographically strong byte values.
        rng.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);

        return saltBytes;
    }


    private static void GetKeyAndIVFromPasswordAndSalt(string password, byte[] salt, SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm, ref byte[] key, ref byte[] iv)
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
        key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(symmetricAlgorithm.KeySize / 8);
        iv = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(symmetricAlgorithm.BlockSize / 8);
    }
}
}
```

The code works, when I input data, its encrypted in the database and the proper Salt is stored with the values. When I want it decrypted on a textbox for instance it works properly.

My idea is : The nurse enters data in the form, she encrypt it with a password a encrypted MediCare number and a salt value are generated by the server and then sended to the SQL server, the MediCare is encrypted in the table who looks like this.

Medicare_ID  - int (Primary Key)
Medicar_Number - (varchar(MAX))
Medicare_SALT - (varchar(MAX))

The decryption password is not stored in the database, and I did this on purpuse.

**I am just not sure if I follow the best practice here, can my information be easily decrypted if the physical server got stolen? They still need the password right to decrypt the data? We need sometimes to get it decrypted in case of an emergency. Is my decryption method secure?** Another concern is that I use 1and1 shared webhosting.

I have set up some more security mesures like that SSL will be activated on the website so the informations are encrypted and prevent eye dropping.

I will ensure the connections strings and inputs are sanitised just in case but in theory only 1-2 manager or nurse will ever manipulate the data.

The website access is protected with a username password with a login control that I borrowed from visual studio 2010.

Thanks for taking the time to read this

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/ Maybe can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the primary questions:

> I am just not sure if I follow the best practice here, can my
>   information be easily decrypted if the physical server got stolen?

Regarding a stolen server: no matter what you do, you will have been pwned.  There is no known security that is perfect against stolen hardware.  Even encrypted hard drives in laptops can be broken given time sometimes faster than the encryption providing companies would have you believe.  Which, if they've gone down the route of physically taking the hardware then they are going to do one of two things: wipe it and resell the parts or crack the data.  Morally (sometimes legally), you should notify all the clients that their data was stolen regardless of what ultimately happens.

I guess the point is: Encryption doesn't mean the bad guys *can't* steal the data.  It simply means that it's going to take awhile.  You encrypt things to buy time.  Time to change the locks, time to inform the clients, time for *them* to change their passwords; and, when dealing with SSN's and other valuable data, time to put locks on credit accounts.

> They still need the password right to decrypt the data?

Not necessarily.  Never mind that you have to store the password *somewhere*.  If they steal your DB server, then odds are they've carried away the web server (which would have the credentials) as well.

> We need sometimes to get it decrypted in case of an emergency.

Regarding an "emergency" decryption: there are two ways to handle this.  Either have a copy of that password stored somewhere you can get to it or crack it.

> Is my decryption method secure?

I would call your method a waste of time.  See below for more info.

---

At this point you should understand that physical access to a machine equates to complete access to its data.  So, barring the idea that you have stored it in a truly secure location with armed guards there isn't a whole lot you can do.  Typical data center security (such as the Amazon cloud) is usually good enough.  However, for government data some companies (again Amazon) have specialized servers just for holding data you've deemed that needs the extra security.  I doubt 1 and 1 hosting does this.

So, let's look at what some better options are.  Because you mention varchar(max) I'm going to assume you have a MS SQL Server.  SQL Server has built in encryption for the database.  Turn this on.  If someone gets a copy of the DB files (not the server, just the files) then they'll have to crack SQL's encryption to get to the data.  I assure you there is nothing you can do to top this and you don't have to worry too much about key management.  This will take care of your "data at rest".  You can certainly encrypt it again, but I'd suggest reading up on the security built into MS SQL Server would be a much better use of your time.

For "data in motion" you should have kerberos turned on for the communication between the web server and database server.  (ie: don't trust that someone isn't trying to listen in on the connection between the web and db server..  Also don't trust that routers are properly configured.. they rarely are.)  Read up on how to properly configure your AD environment.  You should also have SSL turned on for communication between the web server and the client desktop.

Moving past the encryption, there are two primary points you need to be concerned with.  First is the level of access the website has with the database.  Does that user account basically have SA level rights?  If so, you're doing it wrong.  The account the site uses should be extremely limited to just executing those items that are absolutely necessary.  In other words it shouldn't allow someone to drop or alter tables, or even do full selects on data they shouldn't have access to.  This is where the vast majority of web applications fail.  The programmers believe the only thing that will go direct to their database is the web app.  The reality is that injecting pages etc into an existing app is, well, sometimes too easy.  As a side note, this is my primary beef with most ORMs, EF and L2S.  They require way too much access.

I use to say encrypt your connection strings in the web config, but that's generally a waste of time.  After all if they can read the web.config then odds are they have more than enough access to get the app to spit out it's unencrypted contents.  Which leads us back to the access level the website has to the database.  A firm belief that everyone is guilty unless proven innocent is the best policy.

If, for any reason, the web server and database server are on the same physical box: change this.  It's a bad idea and once a website is cracked it becomes trivial (due to how most sites are built) to get sa level access to the db server.

Next, turn on logging.  In the DB you should be logging *at least* both login failures and successes.  In the website, log everything.  Also, turn off direct access to the db server from the outside.  While at it, go ahead and switch the db server to use a non standard port (ie: not 1433/2433) for communication.  Make sure the DB server firewall is properly configured to only allow connections from that webserver.

Go through your code with a fine tooth comb.  Read up on [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page).  Sanitize your inputs.All of them.  Make sure that all DB queries pass parameters and that you aren't dynamically constructing anything.  Disable the SA account.

This got a little long; but I hope it was educational.

Comment: Thanks you, I see now where the flaws are, and I will consider the security advice you gave me. Someone also mentionned on another post I made on a forum about using GnuPG i will look in to this also !

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example how to encryprt and decrypt sensitive information using RijndaelManaged CryptoServiceProvider.

[RijndaelManaged Encryptation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980884/rijndaelmanaged-can-not-decrypt/9983319#9983319)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answers, but I can share with you some thoughts on how I would secure the system. Any existing encryption nowadays will be cracked in the future. It's not a matter of if, but when. With that being said, you may want to ask yourself the followings:

- How long do you want the data to be safe?
  If you are storing information that lasts for 10 years or less, AES-128 should be enough. But if you are storing them for longer than 20 years, consider using AES-256 at the least.
- What do they get if the bad guys cracked the code?
  Besides encryption, you can also employ "security by obscurity" to add an extra padlock, such as saving the encrypted string/information in two or more places.
- Securing from within.
  How security aware are your users? Do they store their passwords under their keyboards, share logins or walk away while the screen is not locked. You may need to put some thoughts on the UI design if any one of those is yes. A chain is only as strong as its weakest link.

Answer (score 0):

- **Shared hosting**: check government requirements, I'm not in the health care field, but I'd be very surprised if there are no rules/laws governing storage of sensitive personal information. If credit cards/ecommerce has PCI DSS requirements, I would think health care data would have at least same level (likely stricter) data protection rules (e.g. [**HIPAA**](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/understanding/index.html)?)
- I don't know much about 1&1, but "where" may also be an issue(?) - **where** are the servers (of 1&1) physically located?
- yet another thought: instead of having salt/pwd generated by user (how long/secure should they be?) Perhaps look into [SQL server encryption options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510663%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), moving the job to SQL instead of users and/or code.
- Decide if data should be encrypted or hashed (storage/retrieval vs. lookup) - re: password = hashed, SSN - depends on usage I guess. [Hash can also be done in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)....

Answer (score 0):

This function is a bad practice, IV's need to be random to be secure, the same IV should never be used for the same key.  This always gives the same IV for a given key making it insecure:

```
private static void GetKeyAndIVFromPasswordAndSalt(string password, byte[] salt, SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm, ref byte[] key, ref byte[] iv)
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
    key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(symmetricAlgorithm.KeySize / 8);
    iv = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(symmetricAlgorithm.BlockSize / 8);
}
```